# jQuery Datepicker value and storing into a php variable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I am trying to store a jQuery datepicker value into a php date formatted variable.

The desired outcome: Example

input field name "reviewdate" = 03/02/2015

input field name "reviewmonth" = 3

Both values will be submitted to a mysql database. I am able to store "reviewdate", but "reviewmonth" remains "null" after the information is submitted to the database.

```
<body>

   <!-- Datepicker -->
   <h2 class="demoHeaders">Datepicker</h2>

   <input name="reviewdate" type="text" id="datepicker"></input>

   <input name="reviewmonth" type="hidden"  value="<?php if(isset($_GET["reviewdate"])) { echo date_format($_GET["reviewdate"], "n");} else {echo "";} ?>"></input>

   <script src="external/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
   <script src="jquery-ui.js"></script>
   <script>
      $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
         inline: true
      });
  </script>
</body?

Thank you so much for all your help!
```

Comment: just use the onselect event of datepicker plugin to get the selected date and set the value in hidden value.

Comment: Your input fieldname `reviewmonth` has which datatype `int` or `datetime`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order for [`date_format`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) to work, you need to initialize a `DateTime` object first:

```
<?php 
$month = '';
if(isset($_GET["reviewdate"])) { 
    $date = new DateTime($_GET["reviewdate"]); // or $date = date_create($_GET["reviewdate"]); will work the same
    $month = date_format($date, "n");
}
?>
<input name="reviewmonth" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $month; ?>"></input>
```

If you want to do this in JS, you need to add a handler for the datepicker to handle the reviewmonth and append it inside the hidden input:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    echo '<pre>', print_r($_POST), '</pre>';
}

?>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<form method="POST">
    <input name="reviewdate" type="text" id="datepicker" />
    <input name="reviewmonth" type="hidden" value="" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
    inline: true,
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst){
        var date = $(this).val();
        var d = new Date(date);
        var n = (d.getMonth() + 1);
        $('input[name="reviewmonth"]').attr('value', n);
    }
});
</script>
```

[Sample Output](http://codepad.viper-7.com/Ng18A7)

Comment: Thank you for the help. I just added the code to the form and submitted the information to the database. The "reviewdate" was capture correctly, but the "reviewmonth" remains (null). For some reason I cannot store reviewdate.  For testing: I replaced $month = ' '; with $month = 'test'; and the value "test" is submitted to the database. I wonder if it is id="datepicker".

Comment: Thanks for helping. There has to be a way.

Comment: @RobSands you have to process the reviewmonth on the form processing as well, it'll only be populated after its submitted, you could just use the reviewdate to extract the month on the form processing before db insertion

Comment: @RobSands if you want to make changes on datepicker click event, you need to create your own handler

Comment: That is a good point. I will try that out. Thanks for the help. I will let you know.

Comment: @RobSands I added an answer regarding that by the way, with a demo

Comment: It look like I got it to work. GetSQLValueString($_POST['reviewdate'], "date"), I will need to format GetSQLValueString date_format ('n',($_POST['reviewdate'], "date")), Does this look right, or do you have any idea? Thanks

Comment: GetSQLValueString(date('n',strtotime($_POST['reviewdate'])),"date"), It worked!!!! Thanks for pointing me in the direction.

Answer (score 1):

you have to replace this

```
 <script>
  $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
     inline: true
  });
  </script>
```

with

```
 <script>
  $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
     inline: true,
    dateFormat: 'Y-m-d'
  });
 </script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am trying to store two variables with different formats using id="datepicker". One of the input fields are hidden and the other is not. Thanks.

Comment: you can define it two times like  <script>
  $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
     inline: true,
    dateFormat: 'Y-m-d'
  });
 </script>                                                                                                                                                 <script>
  $( "#datepicker1" ).datepicker({
     inline: true
  });
 </script>